# Given a list of lists of length x, repeat it to get a list of lists of length n

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like the following.

```
    f = [[1],[10,3], [10,15,16,20]]
```

I would like to repeat this list a certain number of times. Let's suppose I want the final list of lists to have length 12. I could do the following,

```
    from itertools import repeat, chain 

    s = list(repeat(f, 4))
```

This gives me

```
    [[[1], [10, 3], [10, 15, 16, 20]],
    [[1], [10, 3], [10, 15, 16, 20]],
    [[1], [10, 3], [10, 15, 16, 20]],
    [[1], [10, 3], [10, 15, 16, 20]]]
```

I can now use chain to upack the list of list of lists into a list of lists

```
    d = list(chain(*s))
```

d gives,

```
    [[1],
    [10, 3],
    [10, 15, 16, 20],
    [1],
   [10, 3],
   [10, 15, 16, 20],
   [1],
   [10, 3],
   [10, 15, 16, 20],
   [1],
   [10, 3],
   [10, 15, 16, 20]]
```

length of d is 12. But this was possible only because 12 is a multiple of three. What if I wanted to repeat it 20 times or 17 , 20/3  = 6.666667 and the second parameter of the repeat function needs to be an integer.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve? Provide your input and expected output for a few examples, since what you currently have is not enough to understand your end goal. Refer to how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, you want to be able to get a list of lists that is any length, not just a multiple of your input. The following should give you a dynamic way of getting the result you want.

It looks at the length of the input and rounds up to a value just above the desired amount. Finally, it returns a list containing only the amount of values you're looking for.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
import math

def my_func(list_of_lists, desired_amount):
     scalar = math.ceil(desired_amount/len(list_of_lists))
     s = repeat(list_of_lists, scalar)
     d = chain.from_iterable(s)
     return list(islice(d, desired_amount))

f = [[1],[10,3], [10,15,16,20]]
my_func(f, 20)
[[1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3],
 [10, 15, 16, 20],
 [1],
 [10, 3]]

len(my_func(f, 20))
20
```

Alternative method using simpler language.

```
def my_func(list_of_lists, desired_amount):
     l = len(list_of_lists)
     multiplier = math.ceil(desired_amount/l)
     s = list(repeat(list_of_lists, multiplier))
     d = list(chain(*s))
     return d[:desired_amount]
```

Comment: I'd prefer `itertools.islice(itertools.chain(*s), desired_amount)`. It's more efficient (since it doesn't coerce the rest of the values into a list). In fact most of your `list` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: I edited out your `list` casts since it's cheaper to keep working with iterators here, but feel free to rollback if you like casting to list for some reason

Comment: Makes sense. I did a comparison of the original vs. `islice` and they were about the same. The original was 227 µs ± 9.74 µs per loop vs 237 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop. 

Your new update actually returned 237 µs ± 6.51 µs per loop.

Comment: It's all marginal so either method is right. My original may be easier for a beginner to understand exactly what's happening :)

Comment: Ehhh, it's within the error bars. Under large values of `list_of_lists` and `desired_amount` it'll be more obvious where the inefficiency lies

Comment: In worst-case scenarios, casting to list doubles execution time. I tested with a list of `10**6` entries filling a result of `10**6+1` desired length. The list cast version: 10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop, the islice version: 10 loops, best of 3: 48.4 ms per loop

Comment: Good to know! I figured at scale your answer is the more efficient one.